# How to refer a html file in templates subdirectory in <a href='url' tag in Django html template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am quite new to django, the below is my project templates folder structure

```
 templates
    index.html
    about.html
    contact.html
    \student
       index.html
       \Attendance
           attendance.html
           ....
       \Exams
           results.html
           exam1.html
           .....
       \Misc
    \teachers
        index.html
    \hrms
        adminlogin.html
        payslip.html
        principallogin.html
        ....
        ....
```

### urs.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("",home,name="home"),
```

### views.py:

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

till now this is working fine, if I

### index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="u-custom-menu u-nav-container">
            <ul class="u-nav u-spacing-30 u-unstyled u-nav-1"><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-border-0 u-border-no-bottom u-border-no-left u-border-no-right u-border-no-top u-button-style u-nav-link u-text-active-palette-1-base u-text-grey-90 u-text-hover-palette-1-base" href="{% url 'home' %}" style="padding: 20px 5px;">Home</a>
            </li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-border-0 u-border-no-bottom u-border-no-left u-border-no-right u-border-no-top u-button-style u-nav-link u-text-active-palette-1-base u-text-grey-90 u-text-hover-palette-1-base" href="about.html" style="padding: 20px 5px;">About</a>
            </li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-border-0 u-border-no-bottom u-border-no-left u-border-no-right u-border-no-top u-button-style u-nav-link u-text-active-palette-1-base u-text-grey-90 u-text-hover-palette-1-base" href="contact.html" style="padding: 20px 5px;">Contact</a>
            </li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-border-0 u-border-no-bottom u-border-no-left u-border-no-right u-border-no-top u-button-style u-nav-link u-text-active-palette-1-base u-text-grey-90 u-text-hover-palette-1-base" href="" style="padding: 20px 5px;">Login</a>
                <div class="level-2 u-nav-popup u-white u-nav-popup-1">
                    <ul class="u-h-spacing-20 u-nav u-popupmenu-items u-unstyled u-v-spacing-10 u-nav-2">
                        <li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="/hrms/adminlogin.html">Administrator</a></li>
                        <li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="/hrms/mangementlogin.html">Management</a></li>
                        <li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="/hrms/principallogin.html">Principal</a></li>
                        <li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="/teacher/index.html">Teacher</a></li>
                        <li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="/student/index.html">Student</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

We are getting the following error message when we run the project, need help fixing the issue.

```
Not Found: /hrms/adminlogin.html
[01/Nov/2022 10:50:06] "GET /hrms/adminlogin.html HTTP/1.1" 404 4299
Not Found: /hrms/mangementlogin.html
[01/Nov/2022 10:50:06] "GET /hrms/mangementlogin.html HTTP/1.1" 404 4359
Not Found: /hrms/principallogin.html
[01/Nov/2022 10:50:06] "GET /hrms/principallogin.html HTTP/1.1" 404 4362
Not Found: /teacher/index.html
[01/Nov/2022 10:50:06] "GET /teacher/index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 4338
Not Found: /student/index.html
[01/Nov/2022 10:50:06] "GET /student/index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 4344
```

what we need to give in the anchor tag i.e <a href= in html template to open the specified html page in templates subdirectories i.e file mentioned in the below project templates folder structure

```
 templates
    index.html
    about.html
    contact.html
    \student
       index.html            <-- this file
       \Attendance
           attendance.html   <-- this file
           ....
       \Exams
           results.html
           exam1.html
           .....
       \Misc
    \teachers
        index.html
    \hrms
        adminlogin.html
        payslip.html
        principallogin.html
        ....
        ....
```

tried as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="/hrms/adminlogin.html">Administrator</a></li>
```

Add this

```
<li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="/hrms/adminlogin/">Administrator</a></li>
```

Now create views and urls for every page you want to render because Django have inbuilt template loader library.

ulrs be like

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("",home,name="home"),
    path("adminlogin/",adminlogin,name="adminlogin"),
```

and views be like

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def adminlogin(request):
    return render(request, 'hrms/adminlogin.html')
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, we know this method. Can't we do this programmatically in html template page, like {% url '' %} can we do this way, instead of putting logic in views.py & url.py, directly calling to open that page.

Comment: Try to pass variable with url and render that page based on variable passed in url.

Comment: @ajay-ks o for each  and every html page we need to provide an entry in the view.py file? is it not possible we provide a <a href="adminlogin.html">Admin Login</a> and click on that link it navigates to that page without providing a function and redirect logic in that function like normal html pages.

Comment: I'm saying pass a variable with url and then render the template you want on the basis of that variable only. You cannot use href="adminlogin.html" (.html) in href in jinja templates. Jinja has their own way to implement url in templates.